# how to pass a global variable to the reusable feature classpath?

Tags: karate

I am starting to use Karate to test webservices and I want to pass a global variable to the classpath of a reusable feature file.
Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would like to pass a global variable to the classpath of a feature file :                                  

" call read('classpath:API_Services/ReusableFeatureFiles/Login.feature) "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `karate-config.js` is for. Refer the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-configjs

for example if you have the following simple `karate-config.js` file:

```
function fn() {   
  return { foo: 'bar' }
}
```

You will be able to refer to the variable `foo` in *any* feature file:

```
* print 'the value of foo is:', foo
```